# How to get all dates from current week in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I need to simple **current week** list from sale_detail and I am using
Sqlite ,but problem is that condition not work but I check that similer sqlite macth date if `2015-1-9` not equal to `2015-01-09` so may program generate this that sqlite is not compare what is the solution **second**  Condition operator  not working Please Help me !

```
SELECT sale.sale_id, sale_date, sale_type, sale_detail.Quantity, sale_status  p_cate_name, p_cate_size, p_cate_price
FROM sale
JOIN    sale_detail    ON   sale.sale_id = sale_detail.sale_id 
JOIN p_category ON p_category.p_cate_id = sale_detail.category_id
WHERE   sale.sale_date >= date('now', 'weekday 0','-7 days')
     AND  sale.sale_date <= date('now', 'weekday 0')
```

Comment: so what's the type of your `sale_date` field?

Comment: sale_date is a date data type

Comment: Learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve A few minutes for improving punctuation and grammar would make your question more readable and maybe clearer.
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
For SQLite, an MCVE includes a `.dump` of your SQLite database.